# Build kotlin multi platform library that handle Swift specific classes

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

So the issue is I wanted to implement kotlin library with constructor that accept `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` if it to be used from swift. Currently I have a library that have both implementation of kotlin and swift as separate codes with same logic. But I don't know how to unify in KMM beacuse in swift constructor I use `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` from `Foundation Data` and in kotlin I use `ByteArray`. The common goal is that I want to iterate the data byte by byte. So how to process this in common code KMM library?

Also I need to accept list and hashmaps in constructor in kotlin and swift implementation and handle them in common code

(It's currently a native library and nothing to do with platform specific APIS)

Answer (score 2):

Swift `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` <-> Kotlin `kotlinx.cinterop.COpaquePointer`

Actually it's even more complicated because Kotlin doesn't have direct interoperability with Swift and it works like this:

Swift `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` <-> Objective-C `(void *)` <-> Kotlin `COpaquePointer`.

You can add constructor with `COpaquePointer` to Kotlin implementation and use it in Swift.

Kotlin `List` and `Map` will be automatically interoped with
Swift `Array` and `Dictionary`.

See official [Swift/Kotlin interoperability guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#mappings)